# Is there a way to give names to row and column of a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I google it before, the answer was no but I wonder if there is any possible way.

Is there a way to give names to row and column of a 2D array in Java?

Comment: Can you please give us an example of what you'd like to have?

Comment: No as arrays have no name. You can use a `Map` for this.

Comment: Use constant variables that hold the column or row indexes. It's not the same as in other languages that allow string values, but it makes the code more readable. Or like the others suggested use a Map.

Comment: If you want something like myArray["header"]["column1"] (something usual in Javascript) the answer is no. The closest entity in Java to that behavior would be a Map or an array of arrays with constants to "name" indexes.

Comment: Is map much slower than array? I will use the 2d tables to do massive calculation

Comment: If you need to do massive calculations then use arrays. Just store column names and row names in 2 different arrays. (you don't need names for calculations!)

Answer (score 7):

No you can't. 2D array is just array of arrays. You'll need to have 2 other arrays with names for columns and rows

Probably you can use something different (another data structure like Map) if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

More dimensional arrays are normally the approach to avoid classes. For example:

```
String[][] persons;
persons[0][1];
```

If you are confronted with such a code you should first make it more readable.

```
public static final int FIRSTNAME = 0;
public static final int LASTNAME = 1;

persons[0][FIRSTNAME];
persons[0][LASTNAME];
```

A better way to encapsulate the data structure is a class:

```
public class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;

  public String getFirstname(){
     return firstname;
  }

  public String getLastname(){
     return lastname;
  }
}

Person[] persons;
person[0].getFirstname();
```

Or if you want the change to be as minimal as necesarry:

```
public class Person {
  public static final int FIRSTNAME = 0;
  public static final int LASTNAME = 1;

  private String[] personData;

  public String getFirstname(){
     return personData[FIRSTNAME];
  }

  public String getLastname(){
     return personData[LASTNAME];
  }
}
```

Make your choice

Answer (score 1):

Forget about associative arrays.You are in Java now and go for advanced way :)
For this Java provides maps.You need to use the [maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).
Here is a example

```
import java.util.*;

public class CollectionsDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Map<String ,Integer> m1 = new HashMap<String ,Integer>(); 
      m1.put("name1", 8);
      m1.put("name2", 31);
      m1.put("name3", 12);
      m1.put("name4", 14);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println(" Map Elements");
      System.out.print("\t" + m1);
   }
}
```

If you need more deeply,As you are saying
`is there a way to give names to row and column of a 2D array in Java?`

 then need to store a datastructure against a key then it is possible.You may store a Map against a key and then you will call it a multimap which will look like this

```
Map<X, Map<Y,Z>> map1;
```

Comment: Associative arrays are maps. Perhaps you meant "forget about integer indexed arrays"? In the majority of cases you need to index by integer for performance reasons. Using a map would be horrifically slow. Only for very small maps would it benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your requirement is to identify the rows. For that instead of using arrays you can use `Map` which are formed by unique keys.

You can define like

```
Map<String,ArrayList<SomeObject>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<SomeObject>>();
```

By this way, you can put a key which can work as a row identifier as it is unique and add an entire arrayList as its value